# How to register an @Interceptor in a Quarkus Extension?

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to create a quarkus extension that has an Interceptor in it.  I was able to get this interceptor working in a project proper but wanted this for my other projects.

I know with my simple extension that expose JAX-RS/RestEasy extensions it was pretty straight forward, but its unclear how I register an Interceptor.

Here's the code in question:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {}
```

```
@Log
@Interceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    Object around(InvocationContext context) throws Throwable {
       Method method = context.getMethod();
       Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(method.getDeclaringClass());
       logger("Entering {}.{}",
                            method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName(),
                            method.getName());
       return context.proceed();
    }
```

What I don't have is an example of the code required for the `@BuildStep`, but the first attempt was with `InterceptorResolverBuildItem` but that doesn't appear to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, its simply adding an `AdditionalBeanBuildItem` as follows:

```
@BuildStep
    AdditionalBeanBuildItem loggingInterceptor() {
        return AdditionalBeanBuildItem.unremovableOf(LoggingInterceptor.class);
    }
```

Comment: did you have an example